# Rails model provide incorrect result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently writing api service on Ruby on Rails. I have problem with method to show launcher version.

The response should be:

```
{"version":"2.1"}
```

But i have:

```
{"version":"2.1","stat":null}
```

Code:

```
def launcher
    @launcher = Stat.select('value as version').where(stat: 'launcher_version').take
     render json: @launcher
end
```

How i can remove stat null?

Comment: What does this line return if you run this in console:  `@launcher = Stat.select('value as version').where(stat: 'launcher_version').take`  ... My guess is you have bad code in your json view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
@launcher = { version: Stat.find_by_stat('launcher_version').value }
```